# How to disable warnings output from iTextRenderer "createPDF"

Tags: java, pdf, flying-saucer

I'm using this dependency to write a PDF file:
org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer in java8, example:

```
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlEscrito.toString().getBytes("iso-8859-1"));

        Document document = (new Tidy()).parseDOM(inputStream, null);
        ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();
        
        
        
        // Coloca a fonte
        iTextRenderer.getFontResolver().addFontDirectory(pathMarksTemplate, true);
            
        // Coloca o builder //
        SharedContext sharedContext = iTextRenderer.getSharedContext();
        sharedContext.setDotsPerPixel(12);
        sharedContext.setPrint(true);
        sharedContext.setInteractive(false);
        sharedContext.setReplacedElementFactory(new B64ImgReplacedElementFactory());
        
        iTextRenderer.setDocument(document, null);
        iTextRenderer.layout();
        iTextRenderer.createPDF(outputStream, true);
        
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
```

And i receive this outputs in my console:

```
2021-05-19T20:51:59.115-03:00   line 586 column 9 - Warning: img lacks "alt" attribute

2021-05-19T20:51:59.115-03:00   line 609 column 11 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "15%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.116-03:00   line 673 column 12 - Warning: img lacks "alt" attribute

2021-05-19T20:51:59.118-03:00   line 927 column 11 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "10%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.118-03:00   line 928 column 11 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "30%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.118-03:00   line 931 column 11 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "5%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.118-03:00   line 932 column 11 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "50%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.118-03:00   line 935 column 11 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "5%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.128-03:00   line 1,764 column 9 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "33%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.128-03:00   line 1,767 column 9 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "33%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.128-03:00   line 1,770 column 9 - Warning: <td> attribute "width" has invalid value "33%"

2021-05-19T20:51:59.129-03:00   line 1,905 column 10 - Warning: img lacks "alt" attribute
```

Correcting these warnings is not an option due to the difficulty of handling the pdf and the criticality of the system.

Comment: `org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer` is a Flying Saucer class. Flying Saucer uses iText to eventually create the PDF file, but the HTML and CSS processing is implemented in Flying Saucer itself.

Answer (score 0):

The output is generated by [`JTidy`](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

You can disable it by using:

```
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setErrout(new PrintWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
    Document document = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputStream, null);
```